# Only trigger a function in the last iteration of a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, loops

The following code checks if a field is of type file and if there's an actual file in it. If that's the case, upload the photo and update the buildings. If that's not the case, update the building using the old photos:

```
  fields.forEach(field => {
    building[field.name] = field.value || this.building[field.name]
    if (field.type === 'file' && !util.isEmpty(field.photo.file)) {
      api.uploadPhoto(field.photo.file).then(resp => {
        building[field.name] = resp
        this.updateBuilding(building)
      })
    } else {
      building.logo = this.building.logo // to prevent updating logo
      building.floorplan = this.building.floorplan // to prevent updating logo
      this.updateBuilding(building)
    }
  })
```

It works well, but since `this.updateBuilding(building)` is in a loop, it's being called multiples.

How to do it so it's only called in the last iteration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`MDN documentation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) suggest that the callback to `forEach` has three arguments:

1. The element value
2. The element index
3. The array being traversed

You can use it to check whether the current element's index is equal to the last index of the array:

```
fields.forEach((field, index, array) => {

  // YOUR CODE

  if (index === array.length - 1) {
    // DO SOMETHING
  }
});
```

Comment: I can't believe I've done JavaScript for years and I didn't know that `forEach` had an index and an array value. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can check **fields.length** of **fields array** and it will be last element of fields array.

```
if(fields[fields.length - 1]){
 // Loop control will enter in this block in last iteration
 // Enter your update code inside this
}
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: `fields.length -1` since JavaScript is zero indexed?

Comment: Wait, so I can get the element that way. I have to compare it with something else? (Right now the loop never enters that if statement.)

Answer (score 1):

use a count variable with increment on each iteration and use an if condition if field.length is equal to count variable call the function

```
var count = 0;
var fields_length = fields.length;
fields.forEach(field => {
    building[field.name] = field.value || this.building[field.name]
    if (field.type === 'file' && !util.isEmpty(field.photo.file)) {
      api.uploadPhoto(field.photo.file).then(resp => {
        building[field.name] = resp

      })
    } else {
      building.logo = this.building.logo // to prevent updating logo
      building.floorplan = this.building.floorplan // to prevent updating logo

    }
    if(count == fields_length){
       this.updateBuilding(building)
    }

count++
  })
```

Comment: You are using `if(count == fields.length)`. This will iterate through the entire collection to calculate the length each time. It's better if you calculate the length once outside the loop and compare `count` to this value.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
var len = fields.length;
var counter = 0;

fields.forEach(field => {
    building[field.name] = field.value || this.building[field.name]
    if (field.type === 'file' && !util.isEmpty(field.photo.file)) {
        api.uploadPhoto(field.photo.file).then(resp => {
            building[field.name] = resp

            /* checking if it's the last loop */
            if(counter == len - 1)
                this.updateBuilding(building)
        })
    } else {
        building.logo = this.building.logo // to prevent updating logo
        building.floorplan = this.building.floorplan // to prevent updating logo
  this.updateBuilding(building)
    }

    counter = counter + 1;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

How about you create some variables to hold appropriate values in the loop;
After the loop, you can run the update on building using those variables.

**UPDATE**

Oh, you actually need a callback for the update. **You got some async operation in the loop???**